# Create a chained command line in bash function

Tags: bash

I have a question: I would like to create a function that (dependantly from number of entered arguments) would create so called "cained" command line. The current code I wrote look as follow:

```
function ignore {
   if [ -n "$@" ] && [ "$#" > 0 ]; then
      count=$#

      if [ ${count} -eq 1 ]; then
         return "grep -iv $1"
      else
         for args in "$@" do
           ## Here should be code that would put (using pseudo code) as many "grep -iv $a | grep -iv $(a+1) | ... | grep -iv $(a+n)", where the part "$(a+..) represent the placeholder of next argument"
         
        done
     fi
  fi
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

**Update**

I would like to precise above. The above functions would become used as following:

```
some_bash_function | ignore

example:

apt-get cache search apache2 | ignore doc lib
```

Maybe this will help bit more

Comment: This is meant as programming exercise, not as productive code, isn't it? In this case, you could append to **each** generated `grep` command by a `|`, and since this would lead to something which ends with a pipe (and therefore is syntactically incorrect), you could append to it a lone `cat`, which would work as cycle-stealing no-op.

Comment: It's an attempt to automate some task's, aspecially to avoid unessecary repeat (for example: ``grep -iv some text | grep -iv other text)

Comment: This pipe would find all the lines which have neither _some text_ nor _other text_. If this is your only goal, it would be easier to do a single `grep -vf PFILE`, where PFILE is a file where each line holds one of the texts.

Answer (score 1):

This seems horribly inefficient. A much better solution would look like `grep -ive "${array[0]}" -e "${array[1]}" -e "${array[2]}"` etc. Here's a simple way to build that.

```
# don't needlessly use Bash-only function declaration syntax
ignore () {
    local args=()
    local t
    for t; do
       args+=(-e "$t")
    done
    grep -iv "${args[@]}"
}
```

In the end, `git status | ignore foo bar baz` is not a lot simpler than `git status | grep -ive foo -e bar -e baz` so this function might not be worth these 116 bytes (spaces included). But hopefully at least this can work to demonstrate a way to build command lines programmatically. The use of arrays is important; there is no good way to preserve quoting of already quoted values if you smash everything into a single string.

A more sustainable solution still is to just combine everything into a single regex. You can do that with `grep -iv 'foo\|bar\|baz'` though personally, I would probably switch to the more expressive regex dialect of `grep -E`; `grep -ivE 'foo|bar|baz'`.

If you really wanted to build a structure of pipes, I guess a recursive function would work.

```
# FIXME: slow and ugly, prefer the one above
ignore_slowly () {
    if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
        grep -iv "$1"
    else
        local t=$1
        shift
        grep -iv "$t" | ignore_slowly "$@"
    fi
}
```

But generally, you want to minimize the number of processes you create.

Answer (score 0):

Though inefficient, what you want can be done like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ignore () {
    printf -v pipe 'grep -iv %q | ' "$@"
    pipe=${pipe%???} # remove trailing ' | '
    bash -c "$pipe"
}

ignore 'regex1' 'regex2' … 'regexn' < file
```